# Do the spells from the drow commander's magic bolts in "Against the Giants" (from "Tales from the Yawning Portal") require concentration?

Tags: dnd-5e, spells, magic-items, concentration, tales-from-the-yawning-portal

In *Tales from the Yawning Portal* (p. 209), [in area 20 of the Hall of the Fire Giant King](https://www.dndbeyond.com/sources/tftyp/a6/against-the-giants#20CouncilChamberandDrowHQ) (in Chapter [6: Against the Giants](https://www.dndbeyond.com/sources/tftyp/a6/against-the-giants#20CouncilChamberandDrowHQ)), there's a variant drow elite warrior who is mentioned as a commander, and has three magic bolts. The text reads as follows:

> [...] The commander has a *+2 shortsword*, a *+1 hand crossbow*, and three magic bolts, as follows:
>
> - A *bolt of holding*, which casts *hold person* on a target hit with the bolt, as well as up to two other targets within 30 feet of that target
> - A *bolt of blinding*, which casts *blindness/deafness* to blind on a target hit with the bolt, as well as up to two other targets within 30 feet of that target
> - A *bolt of vapors*, which casts *stinking cloud* centered
>   on the point it hits
>
> Each of these effects has a spell save DC of 15 and a duration of 1 minute.

Does "casting" *Hold Person* and *Stinking Cloud* like this require the drow commander to maintain concentration on the spell?

It seems too powerful for a CR 5 creature to be able to paralyze three creatures in a single action without concentration.

Comment: For the record, the encounter listed there without accounting for the magic items is merely Hard for the expected party size and level. The Drow Commander is obviously stronger than a standard drow elite warrior, with more HP and better weapons plus the magic bolts, but this extra challenge is probably an appropriate final boss for a party of 13th or 14th level characters.

Comment: I read this question three times before I realized the first bullet point said 'bolt of holding' rather than 'bag of holding' and now a bolt of holding sounds like it should contain an extradimensional space.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

### No

The [rules](https://www.dndbeyond.com/sources/basic-rules/magic-items#ActivatinganItem) state:

> Using a magic item's properties might mean wearing or wielding it. ... A weapon must be held.

These bolts must (presumably) be fired from the previously mentioned +1 hand crossbow and each "casts X on a target hit with the bolt" and explicitly have "a duration of 1 minute."

#### Who's casting the spell?

These can be distinguished from items that "allow the user to cast a spell from the item" and force "the user of the item must concentrate if the spell requires concentration." All items that allow you to cast a spell explicitly say "you cast" - these items don't say that, they say the item casts.

The items themselves "casts X on a target hit with the bolt"; they do not "allow the user to cast a spell from the item."

#### Are these Concentration spells anyway?

The rules say in respect to spell casting items:

> Certain items make exceptions to these rules, changing the casting time, duration, or other parts of a spell.

These items change the duration from, for *Hold Person*, "Concentration, up to 1 minute" to "a duration of 1 minute."

These items, therefore, do not require anyone or anything to concentrate.

Comment: Further evidence that the bolt is casting the spell rather than the commander is that the save against the bolt is at a different, and higher, DC than that of the commander's innate spells, and that the commander has no other spellcasting capability.

Answer (score 7):

### No, the ability specifies what the duration is.

The stat block specifies:

> Each of these effects has a spell save DC of 15 and a duration of 1 minute.

The specific duration of "1 minute" overrides and replaces the duration of "Concentration, up to..." that these spells normally have.

### Is this overpowered?

No, not really. Monsters often have one-shot abilities that would likely be broken in the players' hands.

Anyway, there's a lot of ways for this to fail.  Consider how much has to go exactly right: First he has to hit with the bolt (and he only gets one try); then the targets get to save against the effect, and then anyone who fails gets to save again each turn (standard for *hold person*). Are the players going to lose several actions?  Yeah, possibly, but it's unlikely they'll be so badly disabled that it makes the whole fight go sideways.